# Importing a json file into Cassandra

Tags: json, cassandra

Hi is it possible to import any random json file into cassandra.
The json file is not exported from sstable2json. The json file is from a different website and needs to be imported into cassandra. Please could anyone advise whether this is possible

Answer (score 4):

JSON support won't be introduced until Cassandra 3.0 (see [CASSANDRA-7970](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7970)) and in this case you still need to define a schema for your json data to map to.  You do have some other options:

- Use maps which sort of map to JSON.  Maps can be indexed as of Cassandra 2.1 ([CASSANDRA-4511](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4511))  There is also a [good Stack Exchange post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55165/cassandra-query-a-column-with-collection-type) about this.
- You mention 'any random json file'.  You could just have a string column that contains the raw JSON, but then you lose any query-ability of that data.
- Come up with some kind of schema for your JSON data and map it to a CQL table and write some code that parses the JSON and writes it to the CQL table mapping to that data.  This doesn't sound like an option for you since you want to be able to import any random JSON file.

If you are looking to only do json document storage, you might want to look at more document-oriented solutions instead of a column-oriented solution like cassandra.